# Solid color that will fade into an image when hovered

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a plain color rectangle slowly fading into an image when hovered.

How can I do that ?

Comment: I suggest you use a `<div>` tag with a solid background as overlay over the image and fade that out when hovering using css `opacity` and `transition`.

Comment: But the <div> background would be under the image, no? It wouldn't work this way.

Comment: No, I said a `<div>` tag as _overlay_ over the image and the `div` tag itself _has_ a solid background. I did not say it _is_ the background. Use a higher css `z-index`  for the overlay which raises it above the image, covering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an element covering a div using absolute positioning and with a background disappearing when hovered:

```css
#a {
   position:relative;
   background: url(https://dystroy.org/re7210/img/curryPouletDecoupe-600.jpg);
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
}
#a::after{
   position: absolute;
   left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;
   background:red;
   opacity: 1;
   z-index:2;
   content:"";
   transition: opacity 1s;
}
#a:hover::after {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 4s;
}
```

```html
<div id=a></div>
```

A CSS transition on opacity makes the change gradual. Of course you can use concrete elements rather than pseudo elements using this idea.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

html:

```
<div class="my-div"> hover me </div>
```

css:

```
.my-div{
    background: #0f0;
}
.my-div:hover{
    background: url("urlToImg");
    transition: background 1s ease;
}
```

when you hover the `.my-div` element it will change its background slowly in `1s`

Comment: This requires the image url to be hard coded. Inconvenient sometimes.

Comment: I know, but the OP didn't provide any html and css so I am just showing him a simple way how to achieve this.

Comment: All fine. I did not say this is wrong. I just mentioned the limitation for others that will read this answer in future. Have fun :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may use CSS Transitions for this:

```css
.img-hover {position: relative;}
.img-hover span {background-color: #000; width: 100px; display: block; height: 100px; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s; -o-transition: opacity 0.5s; transition: opacity 0.5s;}
.img-hover span:hover {opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s; -o-transition: opacity 0.5s; transition: opacity 0.5s;}
.img-hover img {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="img-hover">
  <span></span>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
</div>
```